# Is there a JS library that enables me to make draggable and resizable tiles in a grid, like in the iPhoto Journal?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, iphoto

I am looking for a Javascript library that gives me the same kind of 'sortable' functionality offered by jQuery UI, where I can have many tiles in a grid formation, and rearrange them:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid

However, I also need some additional functionality that makes this a bit more complicated. I need:

1. The ability to resize individual tiles, and have the other tiles nicely rearrange themselves around the resized tile. I have tried using jQuery UI's 'resizable' feature in combination with 'sortable', but unfortunately, the tiles don't arrange themselves nicely after some of them have been resized, and you end up with a mess.
2. The tiles to smoothly animate to their new locations whenever they move, as opposed to just jumping there instantly as they do now.

Essentially what I want is something that behaves just like the Journal-building interface in the new iPhoto for iOS:

http://youtu.be/3HKgK6iupls?t=8m37s

Do any of you know of any libraries that can help me with this (or clever ways to extend jQuery UI), or will I have to write this myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!

http://gridster.net/

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not responsive. :-(